# plotly 3D surface, rename axis's title

Tags: r, 3d, r-plotly

Below is the toy example I have attempted. Is anything wrong with it?

```
library(plotly)
fig <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano)
fig <- fig %>% add_surface() %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(title = 'N'), 
    yaxis = list(title = 'R')
  )

fig
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `scene` in `layout`:

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano)
fig <- fig %>% 
  add_surface() %>%
  layout(
    showlegend = F,
    scene = list(
      xaxis = list(title = 'N'), 
      yaxis = list(title = 'R')
    )
  )

fig
```

[image: plotly 3d with axis labels]

Comment: It works partially.  Extra legend is produced sometimes. May I know why the scene is needed?

Comment: I have seen this before, and discovered the axis is embedded in the scene object. See [this reference](https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/scene/). Also, to keep single legend, try adding `showlegend = F` in the layout.